# Firebase deleted user is able to create documents, why?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an iOS app that checks whether a user is already logged in by checking `Auth.auth().currentUser`. If this returns a non-null, the app 'automatically' logs the user into the app.

If I delete a user using Firebase admin tools, the iOS application will not know about the deletion. It will just check if `Auth.auth().currentUser` exists and if it does, it 'automatically' logs in. However, what is happening is that despite the deletion of a user (an anonymous user), the user is able to create documents in the database.

I have security rules to prevent this:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;

      match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**How is it possible for a nonexistent user to have `request.auth != null`?** The user does not exist in the "Authentication" tab.

---

Sure enough, if I reload the user it gives an error:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser.reload { error in }
```

> There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of a cache that lives for X amount of hours despite user being deleted? I will see whether I start getting authentication errors after some time...

Comment: The user's token will stay valid for up to one hour after it was last refreshed by the app.